# can't get response from a function in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm writing a program that creates a doubly linked list and removes a element with negative value from it. Everything pretty much works, except for the part when I called the modify function and when I try to delete it, program crashes. Any suggestions?

```
/*
*Given a doubly linked lists with +ve and -ve key values.
*Write a function to delete all the nodes with negative key values.
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *prev;
};
struct list *head = NULL;

struct list* create(int);
void modify(struct list*);

int main(void) {

int n, i, value;
struct list *temp;

printf("Enter the count of node :");
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    printf("Enter the value of node: ");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    create(value);
}
temp = head;
printf("\nDoubly linked list is created and the list is as follows : \n");
while (temp != NULL) {
    printf("%d ",temp -> data);
    temp = temp -> next;
}
    modify(head);
}

struct list* create(int value) {
    struct list *new_node, *temp;
    temp = head;
    new_node = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    new_node -> data = value;
    new_node -> next = NULL;
    new_node -> prev = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new_node;
    }
    else {
        while (temp -> next != NULL) {
            temp = temp -> next;
        }

        temp -> next = new_node;
        new_node -> prev = temp;
    }
    return head;
}

void modify(struct list *head) {
    struct list *current_node, *prev_node, *next_node, *temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp -> next != NULL) {
        if (temp -> data < 0) {
            current_node = temp;
            prev_node = temp -> prev;
            next_node = temp -> next;
            prev_node -> next = next_node;
            next_node -> prev = prev_node;
            free(current_node);

        }
    }
    printf("\nThe modified doubly linked list is : \n ");
    temp = head;
    while (temp -> next != NULL) {
        printf("%d",temp -> data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this  struct list {
    int data;
    int next;
    int prev;
}; declaration of a node of the list? What do integer objects next and prev mean?

Comment: Why does the function create use the global variable head while the function modify does not use it?

Comment: The `struct` members `next` and `prev` should not be `int`s, the should be pointers to `struct list`, something like:


`struct list {
    int data;
    struct list* next;
    struct list* prev;
};`

Comment: Apology for my mistake but still the function modify is not running after correcting that mistake.

Comment: Perhaps you want to have a doubly linked list of "nodes", instead of a doubly linked list of lists?

Comment: I was trying to form a doubly linked list of n nodes and tried to delete the node containing the negative key value.

Comment: I meant: don't call the struct itself a list, because that would be the node. The nodes together form the list. Also, I'm rewriting the code, stay tuned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `create()` function returns a linked list item. so you have to assign the return value to an item. Also the definition of pointers inside the struct is completely wrong.

```
struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *prev;
};
struct list *head = NULL;
struct list* create(int); //function prototype
void modify(struct list*);//function prototype

int main(void) {

int n, i, value;
struct list *temp;

printf("Enter the number of nodes :");
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    printf("Enter the value of node: ");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    create(value);
}
temp = head;
printf("\nDoubly linked list is created and the list is as follows : \n");
while (temp != NULL) {
    printf("%d ",temp -> data);
    temp = temp -> next;
}
    modify(head);
}

void create(int value) {
    struct list* point = head;
    while(point->next){
      if(point->data != value)
          point = point->next;
      else{
         printf("Data exists\n");
         return NULL;
      }
    }
    struct list* item = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    item->data = value;
    item->next = NULL;
    item->prev = point;
}

void modify(struct list *head) {
    struct list *current_node, *prev_node, *next_node, *temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp -> next != NULL) {
        if (temp -> data < 0) {
            temp->prev->next = temp->next;
            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
            free(temp);
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\nThe modified doubly linked list is : \n ");
    temp = head;
    while (temp -> next != NULL) {
        printf("%d",temp -> data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: So Is ````create()```` returning something or not? You wrote ````return NULL````, but the function type is ````void````. And allocation of a struct list pointer is being done, here instead of allocation of the struct list itself!

Comment: you can change it to exit(0)

Comment: Please change ````struct list* item = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list*));```` back to ````struct list* item = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));````.

Comment: done. thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of a doubly-linked list does not make great sense.

The list should contain two pointers: to the head node and to the tail node of the list.

So you need to define two structures. The first one defines the node and the second one defines the list itself.

In this case you need not to traverse the whole list to append a new node to the tail of the list.

The function `create` with the confusing name is based on the global variable `head` while the function `modify` instead gets the variable through a parameter.

This is very confusing. As result for example you can not create two lists in a program.

So as the function `modify` gets the pointer to the head node by value then it means that it deals with a copy of the pointer to the head node. As a result any changes of the pointer to the head node in the function does not influence on the original pointer to the head node.

This loop in the function `modify`

```
temp = head;
while (temp -> next != NULL) {
```

in general can invoke undefined behavior because it is not excluded that the pointer to the head node can be equal to `NULL`.

And in any case the condition of the loop does not make sense because within the loop you are considering not the next node but the current

```
while (temp -> next != NULL) {
    if (temp -> data < 0) {
```

So a question arises if `temp->next` is equal to `NULL` but the value of the current node pointed to by the pointer `temp` is negative does it mean that this node will not be removed?

Pay attention to that if you will write the condition of the loop correctly nevertheless either data member `prev` of the removed node or the data member `next` of the removed node or even the both can be equal to `NULL`. In this case these statements

```
        prev_node = temp -> prev;
        next_node = temp -> next;
        prev_node -> next = next_node;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        next_node -> prev = prev_node;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

again can invoke undefined behavior.

here is a demonstrative program that shows how the list and its functions can be defined. Investigate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};

struct List
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};

int push_back( struct List *list, int data )
{
    struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        if ( list->head == NULL )
        {
            new_node->prev = NULL;
            list->head = list->tail = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            new_node->prev = list->tail;
            list->tail = list->tail->next = new_node;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void remove_if( struct List *list, int predicate( int ) )
{
    struct Node *prev = NULL;

    for ( struct Node **current = &list->head; *current != NULL; )
    {
        if ( predicate( ( *current )->data ) )
        {
            struct Node *tmp = *current;

            if ( ( *current )->next != NULL )
            {
                ( *current )->next->prev = ( *current )->prev;
            }

            *current = ( *current )->next;

            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            prev = *current;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    list->tail = prev;
}

void display( const struct List *list )
{
    for ( const struct Node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

void display_reverse( const struct List *list )
{
    for ( const struct Node *current = list->tail; current != NULL; current = current->prev )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int is_negative( int data )
{
    return data < 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct List list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
    const size_t N = 10;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_back( &list, rand() % N - N / 2 );
    }

    display( &list );
    display_reverse( &list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    remove_if( &list, is_negative );

    display( &list );
    display_reverse( &list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
2 -> 4 -> 3 -> -5 -> 3 -> -3 -> -3 -> -2 -> 0 -> 2 -> null
2 -> 0 -> -2 -> -3 -> -3 -> 3 -> -5 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> null

2 -> 4 -> 3 -> 3 -> 0 -> 2 -> null
2 -> 0 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2 -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

See the examples of Vlad from Moscow to have a better understanding of what you were doing.

I shall go trough your code and tell you what I would change.

```
/*
*Given a doubly linked lists with +ve and -ve key values.
*Write a function to delete all the nodes with negative key values.
*/
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

First of all: you're making a (doubly linked) list of nodes, not a list of lists. Call it a Node. Also, you can do a `typedef` to prevent you from writing `struct Node` all the time.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};

void append(struct Node** head, int value); // variable names aren't needed here
struct Node* findLastNode(struct Node** head);
void removeNegativeNodes(struct Node** head);
void removeNode(struct Node** head, struct Node* currNode);

int main(void)
{
```

Try not to use global variables. There are many reasons to be found why not to use them, but in here it's possible to don't use them as well. Imagine having thousands of lines of code, you won't be able to have a decent view on the code.

```
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct Node* p; // temp-<p>ointer

    int n, value;
    printf("Enter the count of node :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
```

You only need `i` in the for-loop, so keep it there.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("Enter the value of node: ");
        scanf("%d", &value);
```

Make sure your function names are clear and tell you what they do. `create()` would tell me it creates a Node, but not that it also `append`s the node.

```
        append(&head, value);
    }

    // this can be in a function! (A) printData
    p = head; // temp-<p>ointer
    printf("\nDoubly linked list is created and the list is as follows : \n");
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d <=> ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
```

Look at what you're doing: perhaps you want to make a general function to split the code? Here you're again going trough the list and printing out it's data members.

```
    // this can be in a function! (B) printData
    removeNegativeNodes(&head);
    printf("\nThe modified doubly linked list is : \n");
    p = head;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d <=> ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

struct Node* findLastNode(struct Node** head)
{
    struct Node* p = *head;
    if (p != NULL)
        while (p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
    return p;
}
```

Since your head has to be changed, you'll have to pass the address of the head as well. Also, split your code a bit, so it's easier for yourself to have an idea of your code's structure. If your function is 40 rules long, it will take longer to find out where the cause of the bug is located (exactly).

```
void append(struct Node** head, int value)
{
    struct Node* lastNode = findLastNode(head);
    struct Node* nextNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (lastNode != NULL) {
        lastNode->next = nextNode;
        nextNode->prev = lastNode;
    }
    else {
        *head = nextNode;
        nextNode->prev = NULL;
    }
    nextNode->next = NULL;
    nextNode->data = value;
}
```

Here as well: the first number can be negative, so make sure you can access the head variable by it's address. Also, again keep it simple and split your code in functions `removeNegativeNodes` > `removeNode`.

```
void removeNegativeNodes(struct Node** head)
{
    struct Node* p = *head;
    struct Node* temp;
    while (p != NULL) {
        temp = p->next;
        if (p->data < 0)
            removeNode(head, p);
        p = temp;
    }
}

void removeNode(struct Node** head, struct Node* currNode)
{
    if (currNode->next != NULL)
        currNode->next->prev = currNode->prev;
    if (currNode->prev != NULL)
        currNode->prev->next = currNode->next;
    else
        *head = currNode->next;
    free(currNode);
}
```

I've tested the code and it should work. Having it worked properly is not important though, it's understanding what happens. I recommend you having a closer look to it. Goodluck!